# Start Tomcat on reboot with different user

Tags: tomcat, centos, boot

Which is the fastest way to automatically start Tomcat on reboot, without use the root user (I created a specific user for it called 'openam') and without using JSVC. I'm running a Centos 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone intereset, I set this in /etc/init.t/tomcat

```
#!/bin/sh

# Purpose: Start or stop the Tomcat service.
# chkconfig: 345 95 5
# Check the path of Tomcat and set enviorment variables as follows in the .bashrc profile
export CATALINA_HOME="/path/tomcat"
export CATALINA_BASE="/path/tomcat"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131"
export JAVA_HOME

case $1 in
start)
su user -c /path/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
su user -c /path/bin/shutdown.sh
;;
restart)
su user -c /path/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
su user -c /path/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Where `user` is your startup user.
And then

```
chkconfig --add tomcat
```